# Cannot style TDs added via JQuery in Angular

Tags: jquery, css, angular

I'm setting up a form in Angular. In the middle of hotel.view.html file, I have a table:

```
<table id="rooms">
   <tr>
     <td>Room Type</td><td>Beds</td><td>Q.ty</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input [(ngModel)]="HotelModel.rooms[0].type" name="type" type="text"></td>
     <td><input [(ngModel)]="HotelModel.rooms[0].beds" name="beds" type="number" class="smallField"></td>
     <td><input [(ngModel)]="HotelModel.rooms[0].qty" name="qty" type="number" class="smallField"></td>
   </tr>      
 </table>
```

In hotel.component.css I have:

```
.smallField {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 50px;
}
            
.bigField {
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 170px;
}
```

The reason for that "display: inline-block;" is that, initially, I was adding a DIV. However, nothing happens if I remove it.

The fields in the table row are displayed correctly.
Now, I need to add a line when pressing a button. I do it this way:

```
$("#addRoom").on("click", function() {
        $('#rooms tr:last').after(
          '<tr><td><input [(ngModel)]="HotelModel.rooms[' + rm + '].type" name="type" type="text"></td>' + 
              '<td><input [(ngModel)]="HotelModel.rooms[' + rm + '].beds" name="beds" type="number" class="smallField"></td>' + 
              '<td><input [(ngModel)]="HotelModel.rooms[' + rm + '].qty" name="qty" type="number" class="smallField"></td></tr>');
          rm = rm + 1;
        });
```

Now, the table row is correctly added and the fields are displayed, but they don't take the "class="smallField", so that I have something like this:

[image]

Any ideas about how to style them? Thanks

Comment: You should **never** use jQuery if you are using Angular.  You will absolutely run into so many issues where you have modified the page in ways that Angular does not know about. You need to find a way to do what you need with Angular only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above **never** use jQuery in an Angular project.  What you are doing here is fairly basic and it can be accomplished with Angular alone.

I assume your data is in an array, so all you have to do is add a new item to that array.  Angular will know about it, and it's so much easier than trying to use a separate library to inject raw HTML that Angular will somehow need to know about and parse.

Just use an Angular `ngFor` loop to show the array.  The button will add a new item to the array, and that's all you have to do.

```html
<table id="rooms">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Room Type</th>
      <th>Beds</th>
      <th>Q.ty</th>
    </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let room of roomsList">
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="room.type" name="type" type="text"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="room.beds" name="beds" type="number" class="smallField"></td>
      <td><input [(ngModel)]="room.qty" name="qty" type="number" class="smallField"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>

<button type="button" (click)="onAddRoomType()">Add Room Type</button>
```

```
roomsList = [...HotelModel.rooms]; //makes a copy of this array into this new array

onAddRoomType() {
  this.roomsList.push({ type: '', beds: 0, qty: 0 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem is that I cannot initialize HotelModel.rooms directly in the hotel.component.ts. I tried doing it in the hotel.model.ts or in the constructor of hotel.component.ts but I obtain alswya two rows of type "double" and, if I press the button, I have three empty rows.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: no problem, you just need to get those values and copy them to a local property.  `rooms = [...HotelModel.rooms];` and you can use it like normal. You will of course need to then save that data somehow by either updating that model or sending it back to the server. It just depends on your app. I will update my answer.

Comment: I googled a bit around. Since the array of values is Ok, it seems that the problem is on the form itself, that can hold only one value..

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with the `name` property that would be duplicated on each loop iteration.  I'd suggest either removing that property to see if it works, or maybe adding the numbered index to the name property if you need it for some reason